# GSON is not mapping values with data class in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, gson

Hi I am using `gson` library to map values of response to model. I am doing it like this but it is not mapping values of response to model. I am getting list of 50 models but values in it is zero.

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideRestApiHelper(
        okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,
        gson: Gson,
        rxJava2CallAdapterFactory: RxJava2CallAdapterFactory): RestApi {
    val builder = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(rxJava2CallAdapterFactory)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
    val retrofit = builder.client(okHttpClient).build()
    return retrofit.create(RestApi::class.java)
}
```

RestApi.kt

```
interface RestApi {

    @GET(ApiEndPoint.ENDPOINT_GITHUB_JOBS)
    fun getJobsApiCall(): Observable<List<JobsResponse>>
}
```

ApiHelperImpl.kt

```
class ApiHelperImpl @Inject constructor(private val restApi: RestApi) : ApiHelper {

    override fun getJobsApiCall(): Observable<List<JobsResponse>> {
        return restApi.getJobsApiCall()
    }
}
```

JobsResponse.kt

```
data class JobsResponse(

        @field:SerializedName("company_logo")
        val companyLogo: String?,

        @field:SerializedName("how_to_apply")
        val howToApply: String?,

        @field:SerializedName("created_at")
        val createdAt: String?,

        @field:SerializedName("description")
        val description: String?,

        @field:SerializedName("location")
        val location: String?,

        @field:SerializedName("company")
        val company: String?,

        @field:SerializedName("company_url")
        val companyUrl: String?,

        @field:SerializedName("id")
        val id: String?,

        @field:SerializedName("title")
        val title: String?,

        @field:SerializedName("type")
        val type: String?,

        @field:SerializedName("url")
        val url: String?
) : BaseResponse()
```

I am calling this API https://jobs.github.com/positions.json. Does anyone know what could be the issue ?

Comment: Any logcat error?

Comment: try with first 40 data it will works

Comment: @MilanPansuriya API is returning more than 40 records so how I can discard 10 records. How do you know it will work first 40

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS No error on logcat

Comment: try to set limit kotlin has issue in looping

Comment: if your loop size more than 40 than it will create issue

Comment: Any known issue for that ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172938/discussion-between-milan-pansuriya-and-n-sharma).

Comment: I tried with 4 records but it is not working. something else issue is there

Comment: I think you need to provide default values or an empty constructor

Comment: @GilGoldzweig I did this `@field:SerializedName("company_logo")
        val companyLogo: String = "",

        @field:SerializedName("how_to_apply")
        val howToApply: String = "",` but not working still

Comment: Did you give all fields a default value? And also try to change the fields from val to var

Comment: Yes I have tried but not working

Comment: could you please try removing the `field:` from the annotation? Does it work?

Comment: @user2340612 I did that too, didn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you rely on auto-converted java code

remove `@field:SerializedName` changed it to `@SerializedName`

don't put them in to `primary constructor`

define them like this:

```
data class JobsResponse(){
@SerializedName("company_logo")
val companyLogo: String? = null


....

}
```

Comment: @NSharma according to the [documentation](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.html), the `Expose` annotation "has no effect unless you build a `Gson` with `GsonBuilder` and invoke `gsonBuilder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()`". Is that your case?